# Access windows command from Linux using Ant tasks

Tags: linux, windows, ant, ssh, remote-access

Can someone share the code for invoking an ant file in remote Windows server through an ant task?

I am executing ant from Linux in my `/home/user` directory.

An `sshexec` task tries in my build xml on linux server tries to run a remote windows command:

```
<target name="Build">
    <sshexec trust="yes" host="hostname.world.com" timeout="300000" username="username" password="password" command="ant -file run.xml" /> 
</target>
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Build:
  [sshexec] Connecting to <<hostname>>:22

BUILD FAILED
/home/userId/BuildDir/run.xml:94: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:557)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHBase.openSession(SSHBase.java:225)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHExec.execute(SSHExec.java:236)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

And sometimes the connection is successful, but I am wondering how to access folders in windows machine in my linux server build file.

Comment: Which version of JSch ? Get more output with <sshexec verbose="true" ... /> Accessing folders via shell command => command="cmd /c ... "

Comment: (Looks like an XY problem. ) You could try tools like Jenkins and configure your slaves.